# How to use array in vb.net for combobox usage

Tags: vb.net

Let me say that i want to return some array by using this method

```vb
Function getKategori() As String()
        Dim a As String() = {}
        Try
            connection.Open()
            Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand
            myCommand.Connection = connection
            myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM kategori"
            myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
            reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader
            While reader.Read()
                a = {reader(0).ToString, reader(1).ToString}
            End While
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
        Return a
    End Function
```

it should be return as like
`{{a,b},{a,b}}` etc, and i want to use that result into combo box by using foreach method

```vb
For Each k In x.getKategori()
            '?some function to add these items into combobox?
        Next
```

How should i do for it?

Comment: in that case you need to return List instead of array

Comment: You can fill a DataTable and use its DefaultView as the `ComboBox.DataSource`. Use the names of the Columns to determine the `DisplayMember` (which Column provides the element displayed) and the `ValueMember` (the underlying value, if needed, associated with the selection).

Comment: @Jimi, it's not wrong per se, but there's no point binding the `DefaultView` because that's where the data comes from anyway when you bind a `DataTable`. `DataTable` implements `IListSource` and its `GetList` method returns its `DefaultView`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney  I think we're saying the same thing :) Since the DefaultView is the object that is actually set... When you name it directly, it's then easier to explain why `dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "[SomeColumn] LIKE '%[SomeValue]%'" ComboBox1.DataSource = dt` will fllter the rows.

Comment: Extra little tip - if yo're going to use Try..Catch..End Try, make sure you have something in the Catch block - otherwise your program will never notify you of the correct error if it fails. You're probably better for the moment, commenting out those three lines while you're still writing the program.

Comment: What, exactly, do you want to display in you combo box? a & b? Are you trying to create a 2 dimensional array?